# how to get different data per minutes

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, progress-bar

I created some progress bars using boostrap 3 which will show some different results every time the page is refreshed. Here is the HTML for my progress bars:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-5">
  <p>Progress bar1</p>
  <div class="progress progress-striped active">
    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
  </div>
  <p>Progress bar2</p>
  <div class="progress progress-striped active">
    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
  </div>
  <p>Progress bar3</p>
  <div class="progress progress-striped active">
    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is my JavaScript function

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".progress-bar").each(function (index ) {
          var percent = Math.floor((Math.random() * 37) + 60);
            $(this).html(percent+"%");
            $(this).animate({width: percent+"%"}, 2500);
            if (percent<79){
              $(this).addClass('progress-bar-danger');
            } else if(parseInt(percent)<89){
              $(this).addClass('progress-bar-warning');
            } else{
              $(this).addClass('progress-bar-success');
            }
    })
});
```

So, I want to make the generated data appear every 5 or 10 minutes. not every page is refreshed, how can i do that based on my script ? Thank you

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Herlina/51Lw7zfe/12/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using setInterval? Something like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".progress-bar").each(function (index ) {
   
    setInterval(() => {
       var percent = Math.floor((Math.random() * 37) + 60);
        $(this).html(percent+"%");
        $(this).animate({width: percent+"%"}, 2500);
        if (parseInt(percent)<79){
          $(this).removeClass('progress-bar-danger');
          $(this).removeClass('progress-bar-warning');
          $(this).removeClass('progress-bar-success');
          $(this).addClass('progress-bar-danger');
        } else if(parseInt(percent)<89){
          $(this).removeClass('progress-bar-danger');
          $(this).removeClass('progress-bar-warning');
          $(this).removeClass('progress-bar-success');
          $(this).addClass('progress-bar-warning');
        } else{
          $(this).removeClass('progress-bar-danger');
          $(this).removeClass('progress-bar-warning');
          $(this).removeClass('progress-bar-success');
          $(this).addClass('progress-bar-success');
        }
    }, 300000);
    
    
   })
});
```

Comment: sorry i put the wrong Js, please check the new one, and i already put setInterval(Function) yes its work well, but the color only appear red.

http://jsfiddle.net/Herlina/51Lw7zfe/15/

Comment: you forgot to add parseInt() in line 7. I try to add it and it worked

Comment: Hey, I edit my answer. the color will change now.

Comment: its work!! but when you load it for the first time, it will show nothing and need to wait because the interval is set to 5 minutes. supposedly for the first load it should show some different results. Thank you in advance